# 編集の撤回はできる？

Tags: サポート, 編集

信用度が少ないユーザーが編集しようとする場合、ピアレビューをしてもらうことになります。
その時に例えば、

- 間違えて編集してしまった！
- 一部編集し忘れてしまった！

というときに撤回はできるのでしょうか。

Comment: 何というか、却下回数が判断材料にされそうで…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

提案済みの編集は、レビューされる前であれば再編集ができるようです。

十分な信用度を持っている場合、あるいは自分の投稿を編集する場合など、ピアレビューが不要な時には5分以内に再編集しても履歴は増えませんが、これと同じような扱いのようです。

[Can I modify and resubmit my suggested edit before it is peer reviewed? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157606/286934)

ただしキャンセルはできないみたいですね。

Answer (score 2):

「間違えて編集してしまった」の場合はレビューする方が判断し却下してくれるので
間違えた場合は特にキャンセルなどを気にする必要はないかと思います。

再編集についてはunaristさんの回答の通りです。